# Auto-upgrading similar VM guest OSes

Tags: virtual-machines, automation, upgrade

Is it possible to handle automatic upgrades of VM guests which differ only in terms of config management? I'm asking about either general or specific technologies which facilitate this. In brief, I have a number of CentOS/Debian installs which can be thought of as a clean install + puppet config. I wish to perform, in an automated manner, a `yum update` or equivalent (`apt-get upgrade`), or installing package X. I want this to occur by taking my VM template, upgrading the OS there, and then re-deploying each VM based on *that* template one by one (after I eyeball the template to ensure nothing's broken).

I don't care if it's ESXi or XenServer or openvz or anything in between. I don't mind having to install 3rd party tools. I'm aware of XenServer rolling pool upgrades, but that's for the hosts only afaik.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're describing...

Comment: Can you tell me what about it is unclear? I'm happy to improve the question, but I think this is a case of "I don't know what I don't know". I want to `yum -y update` a VM template of which I have instantiations, and then run an automated procedure to snapshot each guest VM using the template, shut it down, start a fresh copy of the  new (upgraded) template, and set some basic identifying information such that a puppet request will apply the right config to it.

Answer (score 3):

In short, you are wanting to build a template. On your maintenance schedule, convert it to a virtual machine, boot the new virtual machine, run `sudo yum -y update ; sudo shutdown -h now`.

Once it is down, convert back to a template from a live VM. Since you have configuration management already in-place, you would simply build a new VM matching the manifests of the old one, and roll the configuration to the new one, swap the DNS records and kill the old one.

I have not seen a canned tool to perform this job, but the VMWare PowerCLI (PowerShell plugin for VMWare VCenter) can convert between templates and VMs using the `Set-VM -ToTemplate` and the `Set-Template -ToVM` commands[1].

Once you have the VM (the live representation of the template) up and running, you can issue commands into the guest using the `Invoke-VMScript` command[2], such as issuing your yum commands [3].

---

I was playing with the idea of this, and have a Q&D weekend hack. I have not tested this script, and it is almost certainly wrong, but here is the basic idea to get you started. Note, it has some bad ideas, like including a password in a script, or assuming a flat name-space for your VMs and Templates.

```
#################################
## Convert a VMWare template to a running
## system, apply maintenance, then convert
## back to a template
##
## Note, this naively does not do any error-
## checking and does not specify much info
##
## Please adapt to your environment
##
#################################


Param {
    [string] $templatename ;
}

$RHELPasswd = 'P@$$w0rd!' ;

if(! $templatename) {
    Write-Error "Please pass the name of the template on the command-line" ;
    exit(-1) ;
}

if(Get-Template -Name $templatename) {
    $vm = Set-Template -Template $templatename -ToVM ;
    $guestscript = 'sudo yum -y update ; sudo shutdown -h now' ;
    Invoke-VMScript -VM $vm -ScriptText $guestscript -GuestUser 'root' -GuestPassword $RHELPasswd ;
    Get-VM $vm |Set-VM -ToTemplate -name $templatename ;
}
```

---

1: http://www.mikelaverick.com/2014/06/back-to-basics-creating-and-deploying-templates-with-powercli-part-7/ [4] and [5]
 2: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Invoke-VMScript.html
 3: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-yum.html#sec-Checking_For_and_Updating_Packages
 4: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Set-VM.html
 5: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Set-Template.html

Comment: Yeah, sort of, except I'm looking for some kind of tool out there which will automate the process of killing the old, building a new VM, rolling the config etc. DNS should not have to change as it would take the same network config as the old one.

Comment: +1 for your scripting so far, cheers for that! So, right now we've automated the first step of upgrading the template. The guest re-deployment is actually the linchpin of the question, as well as clearly the more complicated step. I suppose it'd have to be environment-specific and iterate over named VMs using PowerCLI.